# java.lang.String cannot be cast HQL

Tags: java, sql, hql, dao

**Updated**

Error says:

```
ava.lang.String cannot be cast to com.test.test.classes.TblTaxType
```

what is happening is when I add the tag `select distinct taxtcode` error is appearing. But when I removed the select tag like `FROM tblTaxType tbl_tax_type WHERE bfnsCode = ?` everything is fine. What is the cause? this is my code:

```
String hql = "SELECT DISTINCT TAXT_CODE FROM tbl_tax_type WHERE BFNS_CODE = ?";
        try {

                setSession(HibernateUtil.getSession());

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List <TblTaxType>  resultList = getSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
                                                            .setString(0, bfnsCode)
                                                            .list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your entity is probably named `TblTaxType`, not `tblTaxType`. Case matters.

Side note: don't name `sql` an HQL query. SQL and HQL are different languages.

Comment: I think it works, but new error. `java.lang.String cannot be cast`

Comment: Of course. Your query selects a single property (TAXT_CODE). That won't return a List<TblTaxType>, but a List<String> (assuming TAXT_CODE is of type STring). Please respect the Java naming conventions. `TAXT_CODE` should be named `taxtCode`; tbl_tax_type should be named TblTaxType. BFNS_CODE should be named bfnsCode, etc.

Comment: So what part should I change to return `List<TblTaxType>`?

Comment: `select t from TblTaxType t where ...`. Read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using GROUP BY instead by using `DISTINCT`.

```
String hql = "FROM TblTaxType tbl_tax_type WHERE bfnsCode = ? GROUP BY taxtCode";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns TAXT_CODE, this field is a property of your TblTaxType entity, so you can't cast one property (string) in your main entity. This is the reason of your error.

If you need complete entity you must change your query but DISTINCT is not useful in this case because if you extract complete entity, there's ID field (different for each row). If you want a first element, you can add in your query ORDER BY clause with LIMIT 1 (is MySql).

A solution with GROUP BY works only if you use MySql as DBMS because if you have Sql Server the correct behaviour of field list / group by is: a field in field list must be in GROUP BY cluse or must be in aggregate function.